# How do I append characters to current URL in the masterpage?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, uri

I would like to display the current URL the user is on, and append characters to the end of it.
So if the site they were on was google.com it would display google.com/plus.
The trouble is I would like to do it from a master page so I'm not going to know which URL they are on.
Any assistance is greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: You want to append to url based on url and display it on address bar of current page the user on? What exactly are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to display the URL on the masterpage.  It doesn't need to have any functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Uri.GetLeftPart Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.getleftpart.aspx)

For example,

```
string authority = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Scheme)
string newUrl = authority + "/plus";
```

Answer (score 1):

using Request.Url you can know the current url the user requested.